# CakePHP: how to delete haveMany associations with saveAll

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a model `model1` which hasMany `model2`. How can I remove all the `model2s` from a specific `model1`, e.g. the one with ID 1234? This means, in SQL,

```
UPDATE
    model2
SET
    model1_id=NULL
WHERE
    model1_id=1234;
```

But how to formulate this the CakePHP way? I tried `model1->saveAll` with the following array as argument:

```
Array
(
[Model1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1234
    )

[Model2] => Array
    (
    )
)
```

Which means, Model2 just set to a empty array. But this doesn't work. Now, how can I "un-associate" objects2 which belong to another specific object1 in a hasMany (seen from object1 side) relationship?

Comment: just to clarify, you want to nullify those model1_id's pointing to model2?

Comment: @andreas no, the `model1_id`s point from the `model2` table to the `model1` table. And Yes, I want to nullifize them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `updateAll($fields, $conditions)`

```
$this->Model2->updateAll(array('model1_id' => null), array('model1_id' => 1234));
```

Here's the **CakePHP** [Docs](http://book.cakephp.org/view/75/Saving-Your-Data) about this.

Comment: Thanks, this works, but do you know if there is any more elegant/more CakePHPway-like approach?

Comment: Erh that's cakephp way... See the Docs